# how to create a temp table with dynamic field number in progress (openedge 4gl)

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

how to use that with out define a temp table...

```
CREATE TEMP-TABLE tt.
```

Comment: i tried to get data from json file and it desplay in temp table..field number n name change as like json

Comment: You will most likely need to define the dataset and its temp-tables and relations before trying to read the JSON-data. You might be able to create a dynamic dataset from an xml-schema but it's far from painless...

Answer (score 3):

Lifted straight from the documentation:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE tth          AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE bh           AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE qh           AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE buf-ord-hndl AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE buf-rep-hndl AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE fld1         AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE fld2         AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

/* Get database table handles */
buf-ord-hndl = BUFFER Order:HANDLE.
buf-rep-hndl = BUFFER SalesRep:HANDLE.

/* Create an empty, undefined TEMP-TABLE */
CREATE TEMP-TABLE tth.
/* Give it Order table’s fields & indexes */
tth:CREATE-LIKE(buf-ord-hndl).
/* Add field like SalesRep.RepName */
tth:ADD-LIKE-FIELD("RepName","SalesRep.RepName").
/* No more fields will be added */
tth:TEMP-TABLE-PREPARE("ordx").

/* Get the buffer handle for the temp-table */
bh = tth:DEFAULT-BUFFER-HANDLE.

/* Populate the temp-table from order */
FOR EACH Order NO-LOCK:
  bh:BUFFER-CREATE.
  bh:BUFFER-COPY(buf-ord-hndl).
  /* Add the corresponding salesrep name */
  FIND SalesRep NO-LOCK WHERE SalesRep.SalesRep = Order.SalesRep NO-ERROR.
  IF AVAILABLE SalesRep THEN
    bh:BUFFER-COPY(buf-rep-hndl,?,"RepName,repname").
END. 

/* Run a query to access the TEMP-TABLE */
CREATE QUERY qh.
qh:SET-BUFFERS(bh).
qh:QUERY-PREPARE("FOR EACH ordx WHERE ordx.OrderNum < 50 BY ordx.RepName").
qh:QUERY-OPEN().

fld1 = bh:BUFFER-FIELD("OrderNum").
fld2 = bh:BUFFER-FIELD("RepName").

/* Display the order number and the salesrep name */
REPEAT:
  qh:GET-NEXT().
  IF qh:QUERY-OFF-END THEN LEAVE.
  DISPLAY fld1:BUFFER-VALUE() FORMAT "X(10)".
  DISPLAY fld2:BUFFER-VALUE() FORMAT "X(20)".
END.

qh:QUERY-CLOSE().
bh:BUFFER-RELEASE().
DELETE OBJECT tth.
DELETE OBJECT qh.
```

If you are building from scratch you probably want to be using ADD-NEW-FIELD() rather than ADD-LIKE-FIELD().

If you have an XML schema you can also potentially use that to create the TT via something like:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE lRetOK                  AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cSourceType             AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile                   AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lOverrideDefaultMapping AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFieldTypeMapping       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cVerifySchemaMode       AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hTable                  AS HANDLE    NO-UNDO.

CREATE TEMP-TABLE hTable.

ASSIGN
  cSourceType             = "file"
  cFile                   = "ttcust.xsd"
  lOverrideDefaultMapping = FALSE
  cFieldTypeMapping       = "address2,CLOB"
  cVerifySchemaMode       = ?.

lRetOK = hTable:READ-XMLSCHEMA (cSourceType, cFile, lOverrideDefaultMapping,
  cFieldTypeMapping,cVerifySchemaMode).
```

Comment: Potentially is the keyword here. I've never really succeeded this approach. What's worked for me is looking at the schema and/ord xml itself and then tailoring a static dataset after it. After that you can usually populate it using READ-XML.

Comment: Probably not the approach that most people want to use but during development I create a one-off TT then write-schema() to create xsd that I'm confident Progress will be able to handle.  It works like a charm ;)